# CSS - Align Content Below Fixed Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, fixed

I'm trying to learn responsive `CSS` but having difficulty with some basic `css` design. I've created a fixed navbar as you may be able to see in the code below. But the problem i'm facing is that i'm not able to properly align content below it. The content is getting overlapped by the navbar. Can you suggest an appropriate `CSS` fix and not a workaround like adding empty divs with fixed heights? Here is the code:

```css
  *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
        margin:0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: darkgrey;
    }
    
    .title-bar{
        position:fixed;
        margin-top:0px;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: 1;
        background-color:white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        border-bottom: solid 4px dodgerblue;
    }
    
    .page-container{
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .menu-options{
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    
    .menu-options li{
        display: inline;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .menu-options li:hover{
        background-color: deepskyblue;
    }
    
    .menu-options li a{
        color: black;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    .clear20{
        height: 40px;
        clear: both;
    }
    
    .clear10{
        height: 20px;
        clear: both;
    }
    
    .display-bar-1{
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        height: 200px;
        padding:40px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    html {
        font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .caps {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .register_button{
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
        border: solid 3px white;
        font-style:bold;
        font-size:14pt;
    
    }
    
    .register_button:hover{
        background-color:navajowhite;
        color: white;
        cursor:pointer;
        border-color: black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="page-container">
    
            <div class="title-bar">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h1> Multirater Surveys </h1></td>
                        <td>
                            <ul class="menu-options">
                                <li> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> How It Works </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Features </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Surveys </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Plans and Pricings </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Webinars </a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="display-bar-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="" style="width:60%;float:left;font-style:bold;font-size:22pt;color:white;padding:10px;">
                        World Class Service <br>
                        More Than 100 Clients
                    </div>
                    <div class="" style="padding:15px;float:left;width:40%;">
                        <div class="register_button" id="register"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" href="#"> Register Now </a> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="display-bar-2">
                <div>
                    <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                    <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="display-bar-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="" style="width:60%;float:left;font-style:bold;font-size:22pt;color:white;padding:10px;">
                        World Class Service <br>
                        More Than 100 Clients
                    </div>
                    <div class="" style="padding:15px;float:left;width:40%;">
                        <div class="register_button" id="register"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" href="#"> Register Now </a> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="display-bar-2">
                <div>
                    <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                    <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="display-bar-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="" style="width:60%;float:left;font-style:bold;font-size:22pt;color:white;padding:10px;">
                        World Class Service <br>
                        More Than 100 Clients
                    </div>
                    <div class="" style="padding:15px;float:left;width:40%;">
                        <div class="register_button" id="register"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" href="#"> Register Now </a> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="display-bar-2">
                <div>
                    <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                    <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="display-bar-2">
                <div>
                    <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                    <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <input type="text" class="caps"/>
    
        <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("register").onclick = function(){
                window.location = "https://www.google.com";
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>

`responsive.html`
```

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate way is to add padding-top in your div, the same padding as the height of your fixed header.

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes to your **responsive.css** file and it worked out for me.

Here are the changes that I made:

in **title-bar** class

```
.title-bar{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: solid 4px dodgerblue;
}
```

I changed `margin-top:0px;` to `top: 0;`

*Why*? To Set the top edge of the fixed positioned navbar to 0 below the top edge of its nearest positioned ancestor as told [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp)

and in the **display-bar-1**

```
.display-bar-1{
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding:40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I added `margin-top: 100px;`

*Why*? Your navbar had a height of 100px. So i gave a margin top of 100px to your display-bar-1 class.

Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `navbar` has a height of 100px. So you need to start with your `div`s 100px below. 
Add to the first `div` after the `navbar` this:

```
style="top:100px;"
```

Then it should work. It would look like this:

```
    <div class="display-bar-1" style="top:100px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="" style="width:60%;float:left;font-style:bold;font-size:22pt;color:white;padding:10px;">
                World Class Service <br>
                More Than 100 Clients
            </div>
            <div class="" style="padding:15px;float:left;width:40%;">
                <div class="register_button" id="register"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" href="#"> Register Now </a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Other ways would be to create an own `css` class for the first `div` after the `navbar`. Then you could also work with

```
padding-top:100px;
```

or

```
margin-top:100px;
```

```css
     *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.title-bar{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: solid 4px dodgerblue;
}

.page-container{
    padding: 0px;
}

.menu-options{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.menu-options li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu-options li:hover{
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.menu-options li a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.clear20{
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
}

.clear10{
    height: 20px;
    clear: both;
}

.display-bar-1{
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    height: 200px;
    padding:40px;
    position: relative;
}

html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

.caps {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.register_button{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    border: solid 3px white;
    font-style:bold;
    font-size:14pt;

}

.register_button:hover{
    background-color:navajowhite;
    color: white;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-container">

        <div class="title-bar">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><h1> Multirater Surveys </h1></td>
                    <td>
                        <ul class="menu-options">
                            <li> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> How It Works </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Features </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Surveys </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Plans and Pricings </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Webinars </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Blog </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>


        <div class="display-bar-1" style="top:100px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="" style="width:60%;float:left;font-style:bold;font-size:22pt;color:white;padding:10px;">
                    World Class Service <br>
                    More Than 100 Clients
                </div>
                <div class="" style="padding:15px;float:left;width:40%;">
                    <div class="register_button" id="register"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" href="#"> Register Now </a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="display-bar-2">
            <div>
                <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="display-bar-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="" style="width:60%;float:left;font-style:bold;font-size:22pt;color:white;padding:10px;">
                    World Class Service <br>
                    More Than 100 Clients
                </div>
                <div class="" style="padding:15px;float:left;width:40%;">
                    <div class="register_button" id="register"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" href="#"> Register Now </a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="display-bar-2">
            <div>
                <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="display-bar-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="" style="width:60%;float:left;font-style:bold;font-size:22pt;color:white;padding:10px;">
                    World Class Service <br>
                    More Than 100 Clients
                </div>
                <div class="" style="padding:15px;float:left;width:40%;">
                    <div class="register_button" id="register"> <a style="text-decoration:none;color:black;" href="#"> Register Now </a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="display-bar-2">
            <div>
                <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="display-bar-2">
            <div>
                <h1> Some random block of texts </h1>
                <p> Hello world how are you ? what is going on? </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="caps"/>

    <script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("register").onclick = function(){
            window.location = "https://www.google.com";
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```